# When a start date and end date span more than one week, I need to split a row up in 2 or more new rows

Tags: sql, date, split, rows

I would like to begin by saying I'm quite new to sql.
That said, here is my question/problem:

I have a view that has two date columns, a variable column and a text column (for comments).

I need to be able to split up all rows where the two dates are not in the same week. And I need to be able to split the variable value as well, so that it gets evenly distributed, based on how many days were in each week. The comment must be copied as well, so to be shown in each row.

My dataset looks like this:

```
DateIn     DateOut    Amount Comment  
2014-11-01 2014-11-08    600 Good
```

And what I want is this:

```
DateIn     DateOut    Amount Comment  
2014-11-01 2014-11-07    525 Good  
2014-11-08 2014-11-08     75 Good
```

And if the time period spreads over more weeks, I would need it to split up to equivalent number of rows.

I would be very greatful if somebody could take the time to tell me how to achive my goal, using an sql-query.

As this is my first post on the forum, I apologize for any format errors in my post.

Comment: What database are you using?  How do you define "week", is it periods of 7 days from the first day or tied to a calendar?

Comment: I'm using a Microsoft 2005 sql database. I define a week as a 7 day period starting on a monday and ending on a sunday.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a weeks table. I mean physical table or view, where exists one row for every week possible. (We have dates table here, +/- 30 years from now - allows easily create weeks view and similar).

Then you need link your data to weeks table with left join; join condition should check date ranges overlap with week date range (probably you have to have both week start and week end fields in your weeks table - makes comparisons easier).

Then you need to divide amounts between weeks. Because you know date range length, week length and overlapping date range length, this should be trivial :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm afraid I can not figure out how to force my query to add new rows, with the relevant information, based on the information given in your answer. Sorry.

Comment: Like I said, you have to create real table in database, containing rows for all weeks (about 52 rows per every year) - then you can fetch missing weeks from this table.

Comment: The problem is not to acces week numbers. The problem is to write a Query code that can "delete" the original row and "create" new rows instead, using the information from the "deleted" row.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot create such query easily without the help of additional table. Probably you could create some clever self-join, duplicating rows over multiple weeks - but using external table makes such queries much simpler.

Comment: Alrighty then. Lets imagine I have the table you are refering to. I'm still nowhere closer to understanding how to code a Query that will do what I need. That's my challenge and not the hypothetical existance of some other table.

Comment: select ... from weeks join yourtable on weeks.stardate <= yourtable.enddate and weeks.enddate >= yourtable.startdate